# Reading a complex XML file using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to read a complex XML file using LinQ.

The XML file has a lot of levels, how can get all value in one ILIST<> . there are more tags in items.`enter code here`

The XML has the following syntax:

```
<root>
  <items>
    <index_0>
      <product_id>19</product_id>
      <menu_rank>2</menu_rank>
      <menu_country>Guatemala</menu_country>
      <menu_country_code>502</menu_country_code>
      <menu_country_abrv>GT</menu_country_abrv>
      <menu_carrier>TIGO</menu_carrier>
      <menu_value>7.0</menu_value>
    </index_0>
    <index_1>
      <product_id>20</product_id>
      <menu_rank>2</menu_rank>
      <menu_country>Guatemala</menu_country>
      <menu_country_code>502</menu_country_code>
      <menu_country_abrv>GT</menu_country_abrv>
      <menu_carrier>TIGO</menu_carrier>
      <menu_value>10.0</menu_value>
    </index_1>
    <index_2>
      <product_id>21</product_id>
      <menu_rank>2</menu_rank>
      <menu_country>Guatemala</menu_country>
      <menu_country_code>502</menu_country_code>
      <menu_country_abrv>GT</menu_country_abrv>
      <menu_carrier>TIGO</menu_carrier>
      <menu_value>14.0</menu_value>
    </index_2>
  </items>
</root>
```

I have tried this approach but without success :

```
var chartrate = from a in xmlDoc.Descendants("items")
                select new 
                {
                  sub_id = a.Element("product_id").Value,
                  product = a.Element("menu_rank").Value,
                  description = a.Element("menu_country").Value
                } ;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Trying to embed data in your element names (`index_0`, `index_1`, ...) is going to cause you problems. Change it to something like `<item index="0">` if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should works:

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
...

var chartrate = from a in xmlDoc.XPathSelectElements ("/root/items/*")

                     select new 
                     {
                         sub_id = a.Element("product_id").Value,
                         product = a.Element("menu_rank").Value,
                         description = a.Element("menu_country").Value

                     };
```

The XPath query select all elements, whatever the name it has (see the `*`) under the `/root/items` element

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem I see with this is that nither `product_id`, `menu_rank`, nor `menu_country` are elements of `items`

What is probably the best way to fix this is actually to change the XML schema if you can so that it actually represents a list of `items` elements.

```
<root>
 <items>
   <product_id>19</product_id>
   <menu_rank>2</menu_rank>
   <menu_country>Guatemala</menu_country>
   <menu_country_code>502</menu_country_code>
   <menu_country_abrv>GT</menu_country_abrv>
   <menu_carrier>TIGO</menu_carrier>
   <menu_value>7.0</menu_value>
 </items>
 <items>
   <product_id>20</product_id>
   <menu_rank>2</menu_rank>
   <menu_country>Guatemala</menu_country>
   <menu_country_code>502</menu_country_code>
   <menu_country_abrv>GT</menu_country_abrv>
   <menu_carrier>TIGO</menu_carrier>
   <menu_value>10.0</menu_value>
 </items>
 <items>
   <product_id>21</product_id>
   <menu_rank>2</menu_rank>
   <menu_country>Guatemala</menu_country>
   <menu_country_code>502</menu_country_code>
   <menu_country_abrv>GT</menu_country_abrv>
   <menu_carrier>TIGO</menu_carrier>
   <menu_value>14.0</menu_value>
 </items>
</root>
```

after you do that, you can probably rename `items` to `item` in both your xml and your c#

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var result = X.Element("root")
                .Element("items")
                .Elements().Where(E => E.Name.ToString().Contains("index"))
                .Select(E => new { Id = E.Element("product_id").Value, Country = E.Element("menu_country").Value });
```

You should look at Sam I am's answer and try to modify your XML if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You just need another level of indirection to retrieve your Index_N elements:

```
XElement xmlDoc = XElement.Parse(xml);
var chartrate = 
    from a in xmlDoc.Descendants("items").Elements()
    select new 
    {
        sub_id = a.Element("product_id").Value,
        product = a.Element("menu_rank").Value,
        description = a.Element("menu_country").Value
    };

chartrate.Dump();
```

In [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), this yields:

```
sub_id product description 
19 2 Guatemala 
20 2 Guatemala 
21 2 Guatemala
```